# Problems with linux server permissions

Tags: java, linux, file, server, permissions

Hello, everyone,

Recently I have been having a problem with permissions on the server.
I use java. To save the file I'm using file.io and my parameter "files" arrives in the method as MultipartFile. I leave my code below (lean), but I think this is not the most important.

```
public void saveImageOnServer(MultipartFile files,) throws Exception {
    String dirPath = "/var/arquivos/empresa/";
    String fileName = cleanPath(files.getOriginalFilename());
    String filePath = dirPath + fileName;

    File dest = new File(filePath);
    files.transferTo(dest);
}
```

Tomcat7 is the owner of my war (the file in java that I use to run the code) and also of my folder:

```
root@compServer:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps# ls -la -d ROOT
drwxr-xr-x 10 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Dec 18 15:59 ROOT

root@compServer:/var# ls -la -d arquivos/
drwsrwsrwx 4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Dec 18 16:44 arquivos/
```

The problem starts when I set the folder permissions to anything other than 777 and it doesn't save.
This server is the one we use to host our site, but I don’t understand permissions so well, so I’m afraid to put a permission that allows a hacker to execute a script in the server or something.
I've tried to set the permission to 666 and still didn't save it. I do not know how I can proceed and, mainly, how I must not proceed.

I let below first the folder when it's not saving and second the same one when it's saving.

```
root@compServer:/var# chmod 666 arquivos/
root@compServer:/var# ls -la -d arquivos/
drwSrwSrw- 4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Dec 18 16:44 arquivos/

root@compServer:/var# chmod 777 arquivos/
root@compServer:/var# ls -la -d arquivos/
drwsrwsrwx 4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Dec 18 16:44 arquivos/
```

My question is which permission could I use without expose the server and if i use 700 it would be a trouble.

Edit 1:
The 700 permission also works to save the files:

```
root@compServer:/var# chmod 700 arquivos/
root@compServer:/var# ls -la -d arquivos/
drws--S--- 4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Dec 18 16:44 arquivos/
```

Comment: You should be able to do a simple google search to read more about linux/unix permissions. 777 is extremely bad because it opens up that directory to everything.

Comment: I know about it. The question is that 700 is the min permission that is working for me

Comment: Can you have the directory ownership changed?